# Jquery datatables loading from signalR dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

The initial load of the page is handled from the controller, which calls my database to load the existing data to the table. Users have an option to click "Refresh" calls a signalR method that reaches out to an API and fetch new data. The data is passed one by one to the browser and picked up by this function:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    let dataTable = $('#Server_Catalog_Table').DataTable();
    connection.on("AWSServer", (server) => {
        //see if the ID exists then kill it and replace it;
        if ($(`#${server.instanceId}`).length) {
            dataTable.row($(`#${server.instanceId}`))
                .remove()
            console.log("Removed")
        }
        dataTable.row.add([
            `${server.name}`,
            `${server.instanceId}`,
            `${server.instanceType}`,
            `${server.location}`,
            `${server.privateIpAddress}`,
            `${server.state}`,
            `${server.accountNumber}`
        ]).node().id = `${server.instanceId}`;
        dataTable.draw();
        console.log("Added")
    });    
});
```

What I want to have happen, is if it finds a row with the ID, delete it and re-add it so that data is current. However on back to back refreshes, I end up with something like this in the console

[image: Screenshot]

I would expect to see the same number of removals as adds, because the data hasn't changed on the API side, it should just remove every row one by one and add it back one by one. Is there a syntax problem here?

Comment: "on back to back refreshes"....are you sure the remove/add process is complete before you hit refresh again? Maybe disable the button on click and enable after dataTables.draw().

Comment: @FrankM sorry I wasn’t clear, back to back refreshes I meant once the process is complete, I refresh again and trigger a pull from the API. Since I know the data hasn’t changed I wouldn’t expect to see a removed and added for every item in the list.